# creating an easygoing mathematical course that covers basic concepts that are not in main focus of standard courses

Tags: undergraduate-education

I want to know which topics should be covered if one wants to create an easygoing mathematical course that covers basic concepts that are not in main focus of standard courses i.e. what those concepts should be? Course should be on undergraduate level.

Comment: Is the student a water, fire, wind, earth or lighting-style user ? Training which is difficult for one might be trivial for another.

Comment: I'm not sure if your question contains enough detail in its current form to make it answerable. Making a wild guess, might it be something like [A Journey Through the Realm of Numbers](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783030552329)?

Comment: Or are you asking about courses that cover material that is usually taught prior to calculus?

Comment: Seriously though, I think history of math generally fits here, also cool stuff like higher dimensional spaces, visual topology, encryption, perhaps topological data analysis.